# Unit of Work Implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns

If anybody can share a link in which Unit of Work pattern is fully implemented in C#? (not using NHibernate or Entity framework)

Comment: http://www.codeinsanity.com/2008/09/unit-of-work-pattern.html http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx

Comment: http://bit.ly/bF7jL3 (warning: it's an abstract example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out Ritesh Rao's NCommon
https://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon
Or Ayende's Rhino Commons
[http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Commons&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino%20Commons&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
Or here is an article on implementing UOW by Jeremy Miller
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx