# in the repository best to have only methods that update one register or many registers?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-4

I am using C# and EF 4.0 and in my application I have a repository that connects to the database and does all the operations that I need (insert, update, deleted and the logic to ensure that the information is coherent).

In some cases, it is possible that I need to update many registers that have the same information, so if I have a method that allows to update many registers at once, it is more comfortable. In this method, if a register has problems (unique constraints, FK that does not exist...) I could detach the entity a retry with the next register.

However I see some problems with this kind of methods:

1.- How EF is a transaction, if only one of the registers has problems, any of them are updated.

2.- If I update only a register, I can analyze if the reason is that a FK does not exist, unique constraints and so on. If the method update many registers and ther are many registers with different problems, I can't notify to the user the reason of the problem, or is more difficult to analyze and notify to the user.

3.- Perhaps, so the method takes more time because, it uses for longer resources of the CPU of the server, so perhaps others users have to wait until some resources are released. It's true that the methods it is very fast, but if I use a method that only can update one register, the resources is better shared between more users (better multitask?).

Advantages:

1.- I create only one data context, so I think that is more efficient because I don't need to create and destroy it in each register that I want to update (this occurs if I call N times a method that only updates one register at once).

So my question is, when I need to udpate many registers, is better one method that receive as parameter a list of registers and update all of them at onece or better to have a method that only can update one register at once and is the client who needs to call the method N times?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not either-or if you initialize the repositories with one context created outside of the repositories. This is a context that acts as one unit of work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the unit of work pattern. Your repository would contain a method that updates only one register at a time, but your business logic will have a method that accepts a list of registers, creates a unit of work instance and calls the repository update method once for each register.

Businesslogic would look like:

```
public class MyEntityLogic
{
    ...

    public MyEntity Save(List<MyEntity> entities)
    {
        MyEntity result = null;

        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(MyContext))
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
                result = MyRepository.Save(entity);
            uow.Save(); // This will actually make the changes in the DB.
        }

        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

While the repository would only have a method that only accepts one register:

```
public class MyEntityRepository
{
    ...

    public MyEntity Save(MyEntity entity)
    {
        // Update the context if using EF or execute the query.
        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

Ofcourse, you should add exception handling. You could also have your repository control the transaction logic (commit, rollback, begintransaction, ...). Anyway, there's not just one correct implementation of a UOW.

Your UnitOfWork class would then take care of your 'transaction'.
You could even use the same uow for several types of entities if you have relations etc ...

Some links about UOW:

[Unit of Work Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562736/unit-of-work-implementation)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576681/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusRepository

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/entity-framework-with-repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern-and-poco-architecture

Have fun!